# Is outer join single thread in spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, vertica

In vertica database, it could scan the data using all the cpu cores, but when left join the data from 2 tables, looks like it only use one thread on each node. vertica is very bad for outer join as the the join is single thread. how is spark sql, could it do left join using many thread?

Comment: How are you coming to the conclusion that left joins are singled threaded?